# const and pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, constants

The use of const with a pointer can make the pointee not modifiable by dereferencing it using the pointer in question. But why neither can I modify what the pointer is not directly pointing to?

For example:

```
int a = 3;
const int* ptr = &a;
*ptr = 5;
```

will not compile. But why does

```
*(ptr + 2) = 5;
```

also not compile? I'm not changing what the pointer is pointing to.
 So do we have to say that using const with a pointer in such a way not only makes not modifiable what the pointer is pointing to (by dereferencing the pointer) but also anything else, to which the adress we get using the pointer?

I know that in the example I'm trying to access not allocated memory, but this is just for the sake of discussion.

Comment: So did you expect the compiler to assume that only the first `sizeof(int)` bytes are `const`? It makes more sense that the compiler will assume that any memory address accessed with `ptr` is a read-only address ("physically" read-only, or at least read-only in the "perspective" of the function which uses `ptr`).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`ptr +2` simply has the same type as `ptr` namely is a pointer to a `const` object.

Pointer arithmetic supposes that the object that is pointed to is an array of all the same base type. This type includes the `const` qualification.

Comment: So it's just like int + float = float, so const [type]* + some value = const [type]*, right?

Comment: @Root149, something similar, yes. Adding any integer type to a pointer type gives back the same pointer type.

Comment: Only with pointers types decay (everything gets flattened to pointers when pointers are involved, including arrays), where normal integer types get promoted up to a type that can represent everything.

Answer (score 13):

The non-modifiability introduced by `const` depends on where `const` is written.

If you write

```
const int * ptr = &a;
```

(or `int const * ptr = &a;`), the `const` refers to the pointee, so using the pointer for writing to the destination is forbidden.

(OTOH, if wou wrote

```
int * const ptr = &a;
```

you couldn't modify `ptr`.)

In your case, everything involving writing to the destination is forbidden.

This includes `*ptr` and `ptr[0]` (which are equivalent), but also everything involving a modification of the destination address, such as `*(ptr + 2)`  or `ptr[2]`.

Comment: (and note that `const int *` and `int const *` are the same thing - pointer to const, not const pointer.)

Comment: also note that given "`int * const ptr = &a;`", you can write "`*ptr = 5;`" but not "`++ptr`".  Good coverage of the rules is in the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const - the first line of the answer - "Read it backwards" - sums it up beautifully.

Comment: @frasnian This is essentially what I said - `++ptr` is covered by "you cannot modify `ptr`".

Answer (score 9):

Although other answers explain the technicalities of why it doesn't work, I'd like to offer a more general reason: it's the only thing that makes sense.

The problem is that there is no general way for the compiler to decide whether `p + something` is the same as `p` or not, because `something` can be arbitrarily complex. A rule like "Values pointed to by `p` and `p + 0` are unmodifiable, but other values can still be modified" cannot be checked at compile time: imagine if you wrote:

```
*(p + very complex expression) = ...
```

should your compiler be able to figure out if `very complex expression` is zero? What about

```
int s;
scanf("%d", &s);
*(p + s) = ...
```

What should the compiler do in that case?

The only reasonable choice here was to make any value accessed through `p` unmodifiable.

Comment: This behaviour is not caused by any ambiguity in compiler decision making. It is a simple and correct consequence of the rules of the type system.

Comment: @JamesT.Huggett: I'm not sure what you mean by "ambiguity in the compiler decision making"; it's true that the behaviour is a consequence of a typing rule, and my answer just attempts to explain why the rules of the type system were designed this way.

Answer (score 4):

Since a pointer can also be used as an array (think about `argv`), the compiler restricts each access in which the pointer is involved. This way the whole array is read-only.

Comment: Well, argv is just a pointer, since writing char* argv[] is equivalent to char** argv. we just create the illusion of an array.

Comment: @Root149 Array or not makes no difference when it comes to accessing it, as access works via pointers anyway.

Comment: @Root149: Right. And because of that illusion, the compiler doesn't know if your pointer is also such an 'illusion'. It may be used as an array, like `argv`, and therefore every write-access to it must be restricted (no matter if its `ptr[0]` or `ptr[100]`).

Answer (score 3):

Let's think about the type of the expressions.

```
const int* ptr = &a;
```

The type of `ptr` is `const int*`.

So the type of `*ptr` is `const int`. Not modifiable.

The type of `(ptr + 2)` is still `const int*` so the type of `*(ptr + 2)` is `const int` which is again not modifiable.